# extraer nombre de un pdf con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buena tarde,

espero me puedan ayudar.

tengo un pdf que tiene el nombre "nombre_apellidop_apellidom_edad.pdf"
lo que requiero es extraer el nombre del pdf y dividirlo para poder usar los datos por separado, un ejemplo seria este:

Jose_Perez_Martinez_16.pdf

- nombre: Jose
- apellidop: Perez
- apellidom: Martinez
- edad: 16

actualmente estoy usando el modulo PyPDF2 para leer el contenido y me funciona super bien pero no se si con ese mismo modulo pueda leer el titulo y hacer lo que comento arriba

espero me puedan ayudar 
saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si los nombres de tus archivos tiene siempre la estructura:

> nombre_apellidop_apellidom_edad.pdf

no necesitas de nada especial para eso, usa la propia ruta del archivo junto a [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
import os

ruta = "/Jose_Perez_Martinez_16.pdf"

nombre_pdf =os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ruta))[0]
nombre, apellidop, apellidom, edad = nombre_pdf.split('_')

print('''
    nombre: {}
    apellidop: {}
    apellidom: {}
    edad: {}'''.format(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, edad))
```

Salida:

> nombre: Jose
>      apellidop: Perez
>      apellidom: Martinez
>      edad: 16

Answer (score 1):

primero importa tu lista de pdf con `os.listdir("tu_directorio")`, luego haces una lista con las llaves de tu diccionario `datos = ["nombre","apellidoP","apellidoM","edad"]`, luego cada nombre de archivo le quitas el pdf `replace(".pdf", "")`, y lo divides con `string.split(cadena,"_")` y lo conviertes en diccionario con `dict(zip(keys,values))`

```
import os
import string

pdfs = os.listdir("c://")
datos = ["nombre","apellidoP","apellidoM","edad"]
info=[dict(zip(datos, string.split(x.replace(".pdf", ""), "_"))) for x in pdfs]
print info
```

> [{'edad': '16', 'nombre': 'Jose', 'apellidoP': 'Perez', 'apellidoM':
>   'Martinez'}]